# Manipulating list based on the first and second index integer

Tags: python, list, indexing

I need help fixing this code. My goal is to change the last element of the indexed string from "3" to "F" if the two indexes before are an even integer.

```
change = ['E013', 'E023', 'E033', 'E042', 'E054']

def help():
    for i in change:
        test = int(i[1:3])
        if test % 2 == 0 and i[3] == "3":
            subs = [i.replace("3","F") for i in change]
            print(subs)
help()
```

So for example if you have a list:

INPUT

```
change = ['E013', 'E023', 'E033', 'E042', 'E054']
```

I want this to output:

OUTPUT

```
change = ['E013', 'E02F', 'E033', 'E042', 'E054']
```

Right now my code is outputting:

```
['E01F', 'E02F', 'E0FF', 'E042', 'E054']
```

Comment: Do you want to have a copy of the elements? `subs` is a copy. Of do you actually want to change `change` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change just one of the elements in the list, not all of them:

```
change = ["E013", "E023", "E033", "E042", "E054"]

for index, value in enumerate(change):
    test = int(value[1:3])
    print(f"doing {index} {value} {test}")
    if test % 2 == 0 and value[3] == "3":
        print(f"changing index {index}")
        # strings are immutable in python, and .replace creates a new one
        # which has to be assigned in the list
        change[index] = value.replace("3", "F")

print(change)
```

Note that I left the test `value[3] == "3"` that you had, so `E042` is not modified, as it does not end with `3`. If you only need to check if the number is even, remove that.

Cheers!

Comment: Wow! Thank you very much for your help!